# Merge tabs from 2 session of IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, merge, browser-tabs

Sometimes I wind up with two or more instances of IE8 running, and each instance has a few tabs open.

Is there a way to merge all the tabs from all the IE8 instances into just one instance of IE8, and close all the other IE8 instances?

Comment: My professional recommendation is to use pretty much anything other than IE (even IE 8). Firefox and Safari and Chrome are all quite good overall.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you've requested is new with Internet Explorer 9. You will not get this with Internet Explorer 8. With IE9, simply click on the tab and drag it on to the other running instance of Internet Explorer 9 on your task bar.[image: Drag Drop IE9 tabs]

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. If I have to use IE, I create new tabs on the window I want to keep open, and copy the URLs from the other window's tabs. Annoying, but it's not Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do in Firefox by dragging tabs from one Firefox window to another. The Tip Ninja seems to have figured out [how to do the same in IE7](http://myfavoritetips.wordpress.com/2008/02/22/move-tab-to-new-window-in-ie7/) using Autohotkey which would let you merge the windows 1 tab at a time. I think his code should work in IE8 also.

Comment: nice find ... +1

Comment: This should move tabs to new windows, not to existing ones, as the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In the Favorites pane there's "Add current tabs to Favorites" option. Add them to a separate folder in the first window, then in the second one you can right-click that folder in the Favorites pane and select "Open in a tab group". The exact option names may be somewhat different, I have a Russian IE.